Can any of the MacBook Pro computers with Apple Silicon drive an external monitor at higher than 60 hertz refresh rates?
I know some of the MacBook Pro models offer ProMotion Display, meaning a variable refresh rates going higher and lower than 60 hertz, on the built-in/internal monitor/display.
But can any of the MacBook Pro models with Apple Silicon chips drive external monitors at higher than 60 hertz refresh rates like 120 or 144 hertz?
I have looked at the Apple.com product pages, but they do not specify the refresh rates for external monitors.

Yes, the refresh rate can be greater than 60 Hz for an external monitor. For example, everymac.com shows the following for the 2023 Apple MacBook Pro "M2 Pro" 12 CPU/19 GPU 14".

This model supports full native resolution on the interior display in addition to up to two external displays up to 6016x3384 (6K) at 60 Hz over Thunderbolt; one external display up to 6016x3384 (6K) resolution at 60 Hz over Thunderbolt and one external display with up to 3840x2160 (4K) resolution at 144 Hz over HDMI (2.1); one external display up to 7680x4320 (8K) at 60 Hz or one external display up to 3840x2160 (4K) resolution at 240 Hz over HDMI.

